# Configuring URL link for popup window directly in qgis2web plugin?

Tags: qgis, popup, url, qgis2web

I am using the qgis2web plugin (the leaflet mode) and everything works fine. I created few objects in qgis as a points in shapefile layer on the map.

What i need now is to add some url link to each point's popup window (now i can only put there id number of the point, but not the url link). 
I can do it afterwards by changing html code of the final website, which is generated by the qgis2web plugin, but is there any way to do it right in qgis? It would be much more easier to do it right in qgis.

If is it possible, can i add different url link to each point of one layer or the url link have to be always the same for each object of the layer? What i finally need is a different url link in the popup window of each point, which opens new small window with another website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your layer's table structure and add fields to hold any further information you need. Then add this new information for each of your points. If any attribute contains any URLs, qgis2web automatically makes them into clickable links.