# qgis2web Popup Hyperlink Based on Field with URL

Tags: qgis, popup, qgis2web, hyperlink

I have a string field called `PIN`. And I have a string field called `PIN_SOA` which has URLs.

[image]

I'm creating a webmap using qgis2web 3.16. I have popups enabled, and of the two mentioned fields I only want to see PIN in the popup, not PIN_SOA. Here's how it looks now:

[image]

Is there a way to make PIN a hyperlink that opens the URL of the associated PIN_SOA field? For example, I want it to look like this:

[image]

I'm referencing these similar questions.
[QGIS - Convert a text field to a clickable hyperlink, hotlink, or URL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325616/qgis-convert-a-text-field-to-a-clickable-hyperlink-hotlink-or-url),
[Configuring URL link for popup window directly in qgis2web plugin?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174473/configuring-url-link-for-popup-window-directly-in-qgis2web-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a third field to show the link.

Creating a new field with an expression like this:

```
'<a href='+ "PIN_SOA" +'>'+ to_string("PIN") +'</a>'
```

The link will remain the same link, you just style it in a way that is comfortable to you.
To prevent some fields to be shown in the popup I would copy my layer to a virtual layer and use the new temp layer with only the fields you want in the popup.

[image]

Comment: I created a new field with that expression, but it didn't put the whole link in there--only http://www.willcountysoa.com/propertysearch

Comment: Update: It didn't put the whole link because I didn't make the field length long enough.